# Produce formula

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let $a_{i,j}$ any positive integers wher $1\leq i,j \leq 3$.

I want to write closed form for following summation:

$$a_{1,3}(a_{2,1}+a_{2, 2}+a_{2,3})(a_{3,1}+a_{3, 2}+a_{3,3})+a_{2,3}(a_{1,1}+a_{1, 2})(a_{3,1}+a_{3, 2}+a_{3,3})+a_{3,3}(a_{1,1}+a_{1, 2})(a_{2,1}+a_{2, 2})$$

$\textbf{My attempt:}$
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{j=1}^3 a_{j,3}\left[\prod_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^3\left(\sum_{\substack{k=1 \\ k<j}}^{3 \ \ \ \text{or} \ \ 3-1} a_{i,k} \right) \right]
\end{equation*}
We will take $3-1$ when $k<j$.

---

Actually, I want to generalize this. My attempt so complicated to me.

If we consider all of $a_{i,j}$ as a matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} \\
a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} \\
\end{pmatrix}
 then are there any computer program to make formula?

---

$$a_{1,3}(a_{2,1}+a_{2, 2}+ a_{2,3})(a_{3,1}+a_{3, 2}+a_{3,3})\cdots (a_{r,1}+a_{r,2}+a_{r,3})+a_{2,3}(a_{1,1}+a_{1, 2})(a_{3,1}+a_{3, 2}+a_{3,3})+\cdots (a_{r,1}+a_{r,2}+a_{r,3})+a_{3,3}(a_{1,1}+a_{1, 2})(a_{2,1}+a_{2, 2})(a_{4,1}+a_{4,2}+a_{4,3}+\cdots (a_{r,1}+a_{r,2}+a_{r,3}) \\ \vdots \\
+a_{r,3}(a_{1,1}+a_{1,2})(a_{2,1}+a_{2,2})\cdots (a_{r-1,1}+a_{r-1,2})
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a_{1,3}(a_{2,1}+a_{2, 2}+a_{2,3})(a_{3,1}+a_{3, 2}+a_{3,3})+a_{2,3}(a_{1,1}+a_{1, 2})(a_{3,1}+a_{3, 2}+a_{3,3})+a_{3,3}(a_{1,1}+a_{1, 2})(a_{2,1}+a_{2, 2})$$
$$=(a_{1,1}+a_{1,2}+a_{1,3})(a_{2,1}+a_{2,2}+a_{2,3})(a_{3,1}+a_{3,2}+a_{3,3})-(a_{1,1}+a_{1,2})(a_{2,1}+a_{2,2})(a_{3,1}+a_{3,2})$$
$$=\prod_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3a_{i,j}-\prod_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^2a_{i,j}.$$
More generally,
$$\sum_{i=1}^ra_{i,m}\left(\prod_{h=1}^{i-1}\sum_{j=1}^{m-1}a_{h,j}\right)\left(\prod_{h=i+1}^r\sum_{j=1}^ma_{h,j}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^r\sum_{j=1}^ma_{i,j}-\prod_{i=1}^r\sum_{j=1}^{m-1}a_{i,j}$$
$$=\sum_{m\in\{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_r\}}a_{1,j_1}a_{2,j_2}\cdots a_{r,j_r}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to generalize it? I edited my question.

Comment: @bof is it also true for $m\times r$ array of variables?

Comment: @bof You write the general expression for $1\leq i\leq r$  and $1\leq j\leq 3$. Can we express it  $1\leq i\leq r$  and $1\leq j\leq m$?

Comment: @bof I am original poster.:).  I mean $\prod_{i=1}^r\sum_{j=1}^ma_{i,j}-\prod_{i=1}^r\sum_{j=1}^m-1a_{i,j}$

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 I cleaned up my answer.

Comment: @bof Thank you so much. Last formula  a bit explit for me. Can you explain it.

Comment: @bof I think this: $\sum_{i=1}^ra_{i,m}\left(\prod_{h=1}^{i-1}\sum_{j=1}^{m-1}a_{h,j}\right)$. But, for $i=1$ then  $h=1 \to i-1=0$  seems meaningless.

Comment: By convention, $\sum_{i=1}^0a_i=0$ and $\prod_{i=1}^0a_i=1$. More generally, $\sum_{i=n+1}^na_i=0$ and $\prod_{i=n+1}^na_i=1$.

Comment: For example, $n!=\prod_{i=1}^ni$ and in particular $0!=\prod_{i=1}^0i=1$. Likewise, $x^n=\prod_{i=1}^nx$, in particular, $x^0=\prod_{i=1}^0x=1$.

Comment: $\sum_{m\in\{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_r\}}a_{1,j_1}a_{2,j_2}\cdots a_{r,j_r}$ is the sum of all products of the form $a_{1,j_1}a_{2,j_2}\cdots a_{r,j_r}$ where at least one of the indices $j_1,j_2,\dots,j_r$ is equal to $m$, or in other words, $m$ is an element of the set $\{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_r\}$.

Comment: @bof, Thank you so much.  I couldn't  understand this well. To me $ \sum_{m\in\{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_r\}}a_{1,j_1}a_{2,j_2}\cdots a_{r,j_r}$ give just  $\prod_{i=1}^r\sum_{j=1}^ma_{i,j}$

Comment: $$\prod_{i=1}^2\sum_{j=1}^2a_{i,j}=(a_{1,1}+a_{1,2})(a_{2,1}+a_{2,2})=a_{1,1}a_{2,1}+a_{1,1}a_{2,2}+a_{1,2}a_{2,1}+a_{1,2}a_{2,2}$$ while $$\sum_{2\in\{j_1,j_2\}}a_{1,j_1}a_{2,j_2}=a_{1,1}a_{2,2}+a_{1,2}a_{2,1}+a_{1,2}a_{2,2}.$$ The term $a_{1,1}a_{2,1}$ is gone because $2\notin\{j_1,j_2\}=\{1,1\}$.

Comment: @bof thank you so much.